# Gap under sticky footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

My sticky footer works on the "Our Story" page and Hurricane Shutters pages in Safari, but there is a white gap in Firefox and Chrome. Any help is appreciated. the link is www. sloanhp.com.

Comment: Don't link to your website. Instead, post your code here. No one is going to visit an unknown site just because you asked them to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unnecessary extra `<p></p>` in your footer whose margin and padding is causing the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Set the css of your footer to:

```
.footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

That's saying you meant your really want a sticky footer.  Right now, it is just at the end of your content.

The blank paragraph tags won't matter as it is a child of the main .footer class which has a black background.

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution.  After all the complicated "push divs" and the rest, which utterly failed on a responsive design problem, this worked perfectly.